# How to install swi Prolog's graphical debugger on Linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, prolog, swi-prolog

I am new to Prolog and when I try to invoke the graphical debugger I get the following error message:

ERROR: Undefined procedure: guitracer/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)

How to solve this?

Comment: reinstalled it. Now it works, I've probably messed up the installation somehow the first time. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `:- use_module(library(gui_tracer)).` [link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=guitracer%2F0)